# UIWebView with color filter

Tags: ios, colors, uiwebview, filter

Do you guys have suggestions on how to implement an UIWebView in iOS with color filter, i.e. the contents loaded in the UIWebView would be viewed by the user through a color filter which changes the original colors in the WebView... Can't seem to find a solution for this...

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by reading the HTML first, edit its content, then display it in your UIWebView as per below:

```
NSString *urlString = @"yoururl";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSError *error;
NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url 
                                                encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                                   error:&error];

// Edit the html as you want (just by editing the NSString)

[webview loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:url];
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't really want to change html code. It also needs to affect pictures etc. I'm really looking for a filter layer you can lay over the entire screen to change the colors / appearance of it... I haven't found a good, fast method to do so...